# .kafka streams session windows: Aggregation fails intermittently

Tags: session, apache-kafka, aggregation, apache-kafka-streams

We're using Kafka streams (0.10.2.0) for aggregating related events. We're using SessionWindows for aggregating events. The aggregation seem not to happen 50% of the time.
Here is the scenario:

Request -1: All the events are successfully aggregated

- GroupID: abc
- Events:
  E1; eventTime=2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z
  E2; eventTime=2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z
  E3; eventTime=2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z

Request -2: None of the events are aggregated

- GroupID: efg
- Events:
  E1; eventTime=2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z
  E2; eventTime=2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z
  E3; eventTime=2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z

**Streaming Info**:
TimestampExtractor: Stream uses event time extractor for grouping events to windows.

Window Type: Session Windows.
Windows Inactivity period = 2mins

**Stream configuration:**
CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG=0
TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG=EventTimeExtractorImpl

Code snippet:

```
 KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
 final KStream<String, GenericRecord> events = builder.stream(_appProperties.collationSourceTopic);
events.print();
KGroupedStream<String, GenericRecord> groupedStream = events.groupByKey(Serdes.String(), GenericCdsSerde.GenericCdsSerde());
    SessionWindows tmpSessionWindows = SessionWindows.with(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(Long.parseLong(_appProperties.collationWindowInMins)));

    KTable<Windowed<String>, List<GenericRecord>> sessionizedAggregatedStream = groupedStream.aggregate(
            ArrayList::new,
            (aggKey, newValue, aggValue) -> {
                try {
                    aggValue.add(newValue);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("failed aggr session windows", e);
                    return null;
                }
                return aggValue;
            },
            (aggKey, leftAggValue, rightAggValue) -> {
                try {
                    leftAggValue.addAll(rightAggValue);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("failed merging session windows", e);
                    return null;
                }
                return leftAggValue;
            },
            tmpSessionWindows, /* session window */
            GenericListCdsSerde.GenericListCdsSerde(), 
            "session-store";


    sessionizedAggregatedStream.print();
    sessionizedAggregatedStream.toStream().foreach((stringWindowed, s) ->
            logger.info("WindowedTable: window: " + stringWindowed.key()
                    + "start ==> " + ((SessionWindow)stringWindowed.window()).start()
                    + " end ==> " + stringWindowed.window().end()
                    + " windowedValue: " + s));
```

Log for Successfully grouped events:
GroupID: ng28

**Event - 1 Arrival:**

2017-06-01 09:57:23,861  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.EventTimeExtractor:49 - ======= read groupID: ng28 eventID: 1 eventTime: 2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z

[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: ng28 , {"eventID": "1","groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}

[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000003]: [ng28@1496241416653] , ([{"eventID": "1", "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}]<-null)

2017-06-01 09:57:23,864  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.CSIStreamFactory:196 - WindowedTable: window: ng28start ==> 1496241416653 end ==> 1496241416653 windowedValue: [{"eventID": "1", "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}]

**Event - 2 Arrival:**

2017-06-01 09:57:27,158  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.EventTimeExtractor:49 - ======= read groupID: ng28 eventID: 2 eventTime: 2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z

[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: ng28 , {"eventID": "2", "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}

2017-06-01 09:57:27,158  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.CSIStreamFactory:164 - ------- raw stream: key: ng28 value: {"eventID": "2", "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}

[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000003]: [ng28@1496241416653] , ([{"eventID": "1", "groupID": "ng28","eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}, {"eventID": "2", "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}]<-null)

2017-06-01 09:57:27,160  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.CSIStreamFactory:196 - WindowedTable: window: ng28start ==> 1496241416653 end ==> 1496241416653 windowedValue: [{"eventID": "1", "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}, {"eventID": "2", "groupID": "ng28",  "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}]

**Event - 3 Arrival:**
2017-06-01 09:57:31,481  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.EventTimeExtractor:49 - ======= read groupID: ng28 eventID: 3 eventTime: 2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z
[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: ng28 , {"eventID": "3", "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}
2017-06-01 09:57:31,482  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.CSIStreamFactory:164 - ------- raw stream: key: ng28 value: {"eventID": "3", "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}

[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000003]: [ng28@1496241416653] , ([{"eventID": "1", "clientEventID": "123",  "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}, {"eventID": "2", "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}, {"eventID": "3", "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}]<-null)

2017-06-01 09:57:31,484  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.CSIStreamFactory:196 - WindowedTable: window: ng28start ==> 1496241416653 end ==> 1496241416653 windowedValue: [{"eventID": "1", "clientEventID": "123",  "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}, {"eventID": "2", "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}, {"eventID": "3", "groupID": "ng28", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}]

Log for **failed** grouping events: GroupID: ng30
GroupID: ng30; event times for all parts were similar to ng28 group.

**Event - 1 Arrival**:
2017-06-01 10:00:03,004  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.EventTimeExtractor:49 - ======= read groupID: ng30 eventID: 1 eventTime: 2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z

[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: ng30 , {"eventID": "1", "groupID": "ng30", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}

[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000003]: [ng30@1496241416653] , ([{"eventID": "1", "groupID": "ng30", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z", "className": "com.syniverse.cds.domain.Event"}]<-null)

2017-06-01 10:00:03,007  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.CSIStreamFactory:196 - WindowedTable: window: ng30start ==> 1496241416653 end ==> 1496241416653 windowedValue: [{"eventID": "1", "groupID": "ng30", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}]

**Event - 2 Arrival:**

2017-06-01 10:00:09,225  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.EventTimeExtractor:49 - ======= read groupID: ng30 eventID: 2 eventTime: 2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z

[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: ng30 , {"eventID": "2", "groupID": "ng30", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}

[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000003]: [ng30@1496241416653] , ([{"eventID": "2", "groupID": "ng30", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}]<-null)

2017-06-01 10:00:09,227  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.CSIStreamFactory:196 - WindowedTable: window: ng30start ==> 1496241416653 end ==> 1496241416653 windowedValue: [{"eventID": "2", "groupID": "ng30", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}]

**Event - 3 Arrival:**

2017-06-01 10:00:14,546  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.EventTimeExtractor:49 - ======= read groupID: ng30 eventID: 3 eventTime: 2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z

[KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000]: ng30 , {"eventID": "3", "clientEventID": "123", "groupID": "ng30", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}

[KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-0000000003]: [ng30@1496241416653] , ([{"eventID": "3", "groupID": "ng30", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}]<-null)

2017-06-01 10:00:14,547  INFO StreamThread-1 c.s.c.c.s.CSIStreamFactory:196 - WindowedTable: window: ng30start ==> 1496241416653 end ==> 1496241416653 windowedValue: [{"eventID": "3", "groupID": "ng30", "eventTime": "2017-05-31T14:36:56.653Z"}]

After the arrival of 2nd and 3rd event, the previous events aren't present in the aggregation step.

We've tried different combination of
1. cache.max.bytes.buffering: setting to 0 as well as 10kb
2. commit.interval.ms: default value as well as values ranging from 5ms to 2 secs.

Is this related to incorrect or missing a configuration? Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: This is hard to impossible to debug on SO... Did you try to set a break point in your code and debug within an IDE? When your aggregation function is called, can you verify that Initializer is only called once per key? What are the value of Aggregator parameter? You can also try to query the store via Interactive Queries and/or read from the underlying store changelog topic to see what get's persistent there. I cannot spot any problem is your code and also don't think it's a configuration problem. Might even be a bug... But cannot say for sure.

Comment: I've noticed the following difference in your first event of the failed group. It contains this extra bit:  "className": "com.syniverse.cds.domain.Event". Are you sure your GenericListCdsSerde correctly handles lists containing that event? Or by any chance it may fail silently and return an empty list instead?

Comment: Sorry, missed updating this thread on this issue. The issue was that we were using default values for commit.interval.ms and cache.max.bytes.buffering properties which are 30 secs and 10485760 bytes respectively. The subsequent related events that need to be aggregated were arriving at a faster rate (in the order of 30millis) wasn't finding earlier events as it was in memory and not on the disk. We configured "commit.interval.ms" to 5 ms and "cache.max.bytes.buffering" to 1 mb. This configuration ensured that the events are persisted to rocksdb before the next related event arrives.